# Are there any examples that can help me with flutter sms retriever api plugin?

Tags: flutter, sms, sms-retriever-api

Are there any examples that can help me with flutter sms retriever api plugin, i really need an example of how of how to implement it because my app was rejected in playstore due to sms permissions & they advised to use sms retriever api plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There are few packages that can help you with that by implementing the native part of the code (Java/Kotlin & Swift).

- [sms_retriever](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_retriever)
- [sms_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill)

The latter also provides you with a couple of utility widgets for SMS codes.

They both provide a usage example in their *Example* tab.